.NET 8: MemoryCache SlidingExpiration without accessing
My question is similair to this one, but the answers only explain why things happen the way they do, not how to actually achieve the desired solution.
Right now, when defining
var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
{
    // After x minutes of non-access, remove
    SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x),
}
.RegisterPostEvictionCallback(OnCacheItemRemoved);

A cacheItem will only be removed when accessing it on a timepoint t1 > t0 + x'. That means that if I do not access the item anymore after that point, it also will never be removed from cache.
I could set an absolute expiration yes, but that would overrule the sliding window. If I wanted it to stay in memory if it still being accessed, then it would be evicted due to the aboslute expiration. What I want is a simple sliding window with automatic eviction once the item hasn't been accessed in x minutes. I'd expect an internal timer to handle this. It does not need to run every second for performance reasons, once a minute is fine enough for me.
I do not see any configuration for how to check for eviction either.
EDIT
When adding the MemoryCache for DI, there is in fact an option for ExpirationScanFrequency
services.AddMemoryCache(options => {
    // Check for expired cache items once a minute
    options.ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});

but this does not seem to work. My callback still isn't being invoked several minutes later even though nothing accesses it. X is set to 1 for now.

Below is a code sample that starts a timer to check for expired items, which may suite your needs.
Items will be expired from the cache every 5 seconds -- you can change the length of time by changing the two lines:
cache_opts.ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 );

cache_check_timer = new System.Timers.Timer( 5000 );

In the sample, a memory cache is created, and 3 items are added, each of which will expire if not accessed within the sliding expiration timespan:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace InMemoryNetCore
{

   class Program
   {

      private static System.Timers.Timer? cache_check_timer;

      private static IMemoryCache? cache;

      public static void Main( string[] args )
      {

         String in_str;


         // Create a memory cache ...
         // Important - set the minimum length of time between successive scans for expired items (default is one minute) ...

         var cache_opts = new MemoryCacheOptions();

         cache_opts.ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 );

         cache = new MemoryCache( cache_opts );


         // Create a timer with a five second interval ...

         cache_check_timer = new System.Timers.Timer( 5000 );

         cache_check_timer.AutoReset = true;

         cache_check_timer.Elapsed += cache_check;

         cache_check_timer.Start();


         // Create cache item which executes call back function

         var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
             .SetPriority( Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheItemPriority.Normal )
             .SetSlidingExpiration( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 5 ) )
             .RegisterPostEvictionCallback( callback: cache_item_removed );


         // add cache Item with options of callback

         cache.Set( 1, "Cache Item 1", cacheEntryOptions );

         cache.Set( 2, "Cache Item 2", cacheEntryOptions );

         cache.Set( 3, "Cache Item 3", cacheEntryOptions );


         // Get user input to terminate program ...

         in_str = String.Empty;

         while ( !"QUIT".Equals( in_str ) )
         {

            Console.Write( "Enter QUIT to end: " );

            in_str = Console.ReadLine();

         }


         // Stop and dispose of timer ...

         cache_check_timer.Stop();
         
         cache_check_timer.Dispose();


         Console.WriteLine( "\nProgram ended" );

      }

      // Used to issue a Get request to the cache using a key value that we
      // know does not exist - only to invoke the internal scan for expired items ...
      private static void cache_check( object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e )
      {

         //Console.WriteLine( "Here in cache_check" );
         //Console.WriteLine( "Timer event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime );

         if ( cache is not null )
         {

            // Issue a Get for a key that does not exist ...

           _ = cache.Get( -1 );

         }

      }


      // Callback when cached items are removed ...
      private static void cache_item_removed( object key, object? value, EvictionReason reason, object? state )
      {

         Console.Write( "\nCache key: " + key + " removed from cache due to: " + reason );

      }

   }

}



A cacheItem will only be removed when accessing it on a timepoint t1 > t0 + x'. That means that if I do not access the item anymore after that point, it also will never be removed from cache.

That is not a fully correct statement. As explained in the link form one of the answers, any activity on the cache can cause the eviction, for example adding a new item to the cache, or even reading another key:

We didn't want a timer always running on an otherwise idle site. Any activity on the cache (Get, Set, Remove) can trigger a background scan for expired items. A timer on the CancellationTokenSource (CancelAfter) would also remove the entry and trigger a scan for expired items.

See the usages of the StartScanForExpiredItemsIfNeeded in the source code - it is called in several methods like Remove, SetEntry, TryGetValue and EntryExpired.
For example you can play with the following:
// some setup
var sc = new ServiceCollection();
sc.AddMemoryCache(opts =>
{
    opts.ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
});
var sp = sc.BuildServiceProvider();
var cache = sp.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();
// eviction "debugger"
PostEvictionDelegate OnCacheItemRemoved = (key, value, reason, state) => Console.WriteLine($"{key} {value} {reason} {state}");
// entry to be evicted
var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
    {
        SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
    }
    .RegisterPostEvictionCallback(OnCacheItemRemoved);
cache.Set("1", 1, options);
// some other entry
cache.Set("not1", 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    await Task.Delay(50);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    // uncommenting any of the following lines 
    // triggers expiration in the Release mode:

    // cache.Set("1" + i, 1, options);
    // cache.Get<int>("not1");
    // cache.TryGetValue("notPresent", out _);
}

There is not much you can do here except for some hacky approach like:

creating a timer and either accessing some key (for example dummy one) or calling MemoryCache.Compact manually (i.e. something like (cache as MemoryCache)?.Compact(0.01)) when it is elapsed
adding some dummy cache entry with absolute expiration (and readding it on expiration).

